# How do I figure out the variance explained in tfidf matrix with kmeans?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, tf-idf

I am fairly new with working with text data.

I have a data frame of about 300,000 unique product names and I am trying to use k means to cluster similar names together. I used sklearn's tfidfvectorizer to vectorize the names and convert to a tf-idf matrix.

Next I ran k means on the tf-idf matrix with number of clusters ranging from 5 to 10.

I am on stuck on error when trying to calculate variance explained for `D_k` `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

I want to plot the variance explained v. number of clusters plot so I can distinguish where the elbow is.

I am referencing https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6508/k-means-incoherent-behaviour-choosing-k-with-elbow-method-bic-variance-explain

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
#define vectorizer parameters

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True,
                                   stop_words = 'english',
                                   ngram_range=(2,4))

%time tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(unique_names)

# clustering with kmeans
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

num_clusters = range(5,10)

%time KM = [KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(tfidf_matrix) for k in num_clusters]


from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, pdist

centroids = [k.cluster_centers_ for k in KM]
D_k = [cdist(tfidf_matrix, cent) for cent in centroids]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should convert your `tfidf_matrix` (which is sparse) into a proper array.

```
D_k = [cdist(tfidf_matrix.toarray(), cent) for cent in centroids]
```

This worked for me.